# Where does reviewboard store the diffs?

Tags: review-board

Just start to use reviewboard,and I am so curious of where does reviewboard store the diffs?

Should it be stored in database?I can not find the details in the reviewboard official website.
Any hint will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Review board stores all details about reviews in a backend database that you specify during setup. I use it with MySQL. You can find the database settings in `<RB home>/conf/settings_local.py` file.

BTW, is there any reason why you need this information. If you are using RB, these things should be transparent to you.